# Firestore rules query FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a "mail" collection on firestore . I'm trying to set up the security rules so that only the owner author can access control according to uid in fields.

/mail/unique_id

```
{
author: "RPH6j0eZc2QrDhvsQJhDDFApjnj1"
date: "2022-11-23T10:57:13.580Z"
status: "ongoing"
}
```

firestore rule :

```
match /mail/{mailId}{
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;

 }
```

function post

```
this.db.collection('mail').add(data)
```

reading from collection mail

```
  this.db.collection('mail',ref=>ref.where('author','==',this.uid)).get().subscribe(res => { })
```

result : l can read from firestore database but, when l try to push new data l have an error

```
FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can read from firestore database but, when I try to push new data I
> have an error

This is because for a **read** rule you have to use `resource.data` BUT for a **write** rule you need to use `request.resource.data`.

So you need to separate into two rules:

```
match /mail/{mailId}{
   allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;
   allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author;
 }
```

More details in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation).

Comment: Jesus, i spend 12 hours to solve it. i didn't note that. Thank you so much